# Is Docker Toolbox or Docker for Mac beneficial over virtualization solutions?

Tags: docker, virtualization, docker-machine

Initially [Docker for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/) leveraged the namespace, cgroup primitives to provide the containerization solution on Linux platform. It used [LXC](http://lxc.sourceforge.net) and later on [runC](https://runc.io) to jail docker processes. While they are extending the support for docker on Mac/Windows, seems that they are taking an inelegant workaround that beats the whole purpose of using containerization over virtualization.

[Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/) used [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io) Linux (based on a stripped down version of Tiny Core) to host docker containers. boot2docker runs on Oracle Virtualbox.

[Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/) runs Alpine Linux on OS X Yosemite's native virtualization called [Hypervisor framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DriversKernelHardware/Reference/Hypervisor/). The interfacing is realized through [Hyperkit](https://github.com/docker/HyperKit/) built on top of [xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve) (an OS X port of [bhyve](http://bhyve.org)).

[Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/) runs on Hyper-V virtualization framework on Windows 10.

The [reason](https://docs.docker.com/engine/faq/) behind using docker (in general, containers) over traditional VMs is negligible overhead and near native performance. Conainers has to be lightweight to be useful.

> **How do containers compare to virtual machines?**
>
> They are complementary. VMs are best used to allocate chunks of
>   hardware resources. Containers operate at the process level, which
>   makes them very lightweight and perfect as a unit of software
>   delivery.

As both Docker for Mac/Windows rely on some virtualization technology behind the scene, is using docker on these platform still retain its relevance? Doesn't using virtualization to emulate containerization beat the whole purpose of switching to docker framework? Just as a side note, this [article](https://shinpeinkt.svbtle.com/why-i-wont-use-docker-on-my-macosx), too, supports my viewpoint.

Answer (score 2):

> As both Docker for Mac/Windows rely on some virtualization technology behind the scene, is using docker on these platform still retain its relevance?

Of course. Pending full native container support on those platform, you still benefit from the main advantages of docker: service discovery, orchestration (kubernetes/swarm) and monitoring.

Those services are easier to scale as container as they would be as individual VMs.

> Doesn't using virtualization to emulate containerization beat the whole purpose of switching to docker framework?

No because without the docker framework, you would be left with *one* VM in which *all* your services would have to live, without the benefit of isolation and individual upgrade.

Comment: "No because without the docker framework, you would be left with one VM in which all your services would have to live..." - what problem would it lead to if one adapts the simple solution of one service per VM?

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock it leads to all the problem CPU, memory and disk isolation resolve: you cannot manage each part of your service without potentially breaking something else in your VM. You cannot *easily* scale (swpan up multiple instance of the same component within a service, like multiple workers or http web servers)